# Disable an anchor or hyperlink if image not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, anchor

I have an **image** tag enclosed in an **anchor** element like this:

```
<a href='$image'><img alt='No Image' src='$image'></a>
```

I find that if the image is absent, I can still click on the link. I want to *disable* the link if the image is absent. What is the best way to do this?

**Update**:

I have tried mplungjan's solution below but it didn't work. I am willing to try jquery if javascript can't do the job.

Comment: I fixed my solutions (I was using parent instead of parentNode) it now works and one of the solutions is replacing the link with text, the other replaces the image with text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version works:

```
<a href='$image'>
    <img alt='No Image' src='$image' onError="this.parentNode.onclick=function() {return(false);}">
</a>​
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/2jb4G/

Or, using a common function that you can use in multiple places:

```
<script>
function blockParentLink() {
    this.parentNode.onclick = function() {return(false);}
}
</script>

<a href='$image'>
    <img alt='No Image' src='$image' onError="blockParentLink()">
</a>​
```

Personally, I think it might just make sense to hide it if it doesn't display rather than block clicks:

```
<a href='$image'>
    <img alt='No Image' src='$image' onError="this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';">
</a>​
```

You can see the hide version here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/KVUUM/

Comment: Thanks a million! This works perfect. I am impressed. Thank you :)

Comment: @BenHuh - I just added another option which might be better.

Comment: I need to display a "No Image" alternate text. That is why I am not hiding the image if it is not found. Thanks, you deserve more thumbs up.

Answer (score 2):

Disable=true did not work for me

These did (using parentNode ! )

InnerHTML and onclick:

```
<a href='#'><img alt='No Image' src='$image'
    onError="this.parentNode.onclick=function(){return false};
    this.parentNode.innerHTML='Image not available'"></a>
```

---

Or remove it:

```
<a href='$image'><img alt='No Image' src='$image' 
onError="var lnk= this.parentNode; lnk.parentNode.removeChild(lnk)"></a>
```

---

Or replace it:

```
<a href='$image'><img alt='No Image' src='$image' 
onError="var lnk= this.parentNode;
lnk.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode('No image'), lnk)"></a>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/HNrZY/)

Comment: All the above doesn't work. My browser doesn't seem to be detecting `this.parent`. I am using firefox 10.

Comment: @BenHuh - That's because the proper javascript is `this.parentNode`, not `this.parent`.

Comment: @jfriend00, thanks for replying me. I have changed code to `parentNode`. But it didn't work too. Could it be something to do with the DOM initialisation? Thanks.

Comment: @BenHuh - I wrote [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9920685/816620) that actually works.

Comment: Fixed. I was thinking of parent() from jQuery when I wrote the code

Answer (score 0):

This is a small piece of code I found that may be useful to you

```
<img src="http://www.someurl.com/image.gif" height="100" width="100" onerror="alert('Image missing')">
```

instead of ALERT you can call a jquery function to remove the hyperlink. Do let me know if you need help with the Jquery function!

Comment: Would prefer if you can present the function since it could help other users too.